# Horizontally scale discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking to allow my discord.py bot to scale horizontally for extra reliability.

I'm aware of things like AutoShardedClient, which would be a great way to do this, but I'm not sure if it'll work across multiple instances. Is there a reasonably simple way to get this to work? And if so, could you give me some tips?

Scaling the hardware is fine and I've got that ready to go, I just need some way of getting the bot to shard itself and then for it to make sure each guild only gets a single shard assigned, regardless of the number of bot instances I'm running.

Comment: Is there a reason/benefit to why you want 1to1 guild to shard? I'm on the same boat, trying to scale my bot horizontally, so I just wanted to hear some insight.

Comment: I wouldn't want 1 to 1 guild to shard, but I would want to be able to have multiple containers running the bot, as it is more fault resistant and scalable. Currently thinking I might have to use manual sharding and pass in the shard configuration to each container from a central system somwhere.

Comment: I see. I couldn't find sufficient information on running multiple instance of the same bot, so I scaled my bot by turning all the computational functions into an external API, and running multiple API nodes in a cluster with load balancing.  
I have no idea if this is the right way of doing, but at least it will scale well.

Comment: That is actually what I have done too, but I'm still going to try and make it so the bot can scale at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```py
# Instance one
mybot = commands.AutoShardedBot(shard_count=8, shard_ids=[0, 1, 2, 3], ...)
mybot.run(token)
```

```py
# Instance two
mybot = commands.AutoShardedBot(shard_count=8, shard_ids=[4, 5, 6, 7], ...)
mybot.run(token)
```

Shards 0, 1, 2, and 3 will run on the first instance, and the other 4 on the second instance. This code specifically isn't how you should do it, but it demonstrates the general concept.

Comment: How would you be able to extend this across `n` amount of guilds that you do not know you may get? Is there a way to get different instances dynamically on-the-run?

Comment: @12944qwerty this is handled automatically by AutoShardedClient. The shard id to use is determined by two variables: the number of shards and the guild id. The above code would literally work and launch the bot on two clusters and 8 shards.

Comment: What would have happened if you needed 9 shards or more?

Comment: This is a nice explanation of doing it. I reckon I could probably hook this up to my API and database to coordinate sharding.

Comment: @12944qwerty you would change on of the shard_ids to include an extra shard, and change shard_count to 9 on both classes.

Comment: What if it happens while the bot is running? I want it to be running dynamically, not me having to change it manually.

Comment: @12944qwerty unfortunately there is no way to increase the number of shards while it is running (at least as far as I know). This means you wouldn't be able to scale without restarting.

Comment: Seems like you just have to do a rolling shutdown.  Each instance is shutdown, one at a time and the number is increased and it is restarted.  Once the whole cluster has been restarted you are now up with more shards